Trying to deploy a console app in vm that runs as background service
i am trying to deploy a console app that runs as background service the console app takes screen shots of users current screen and save it in blob container the code is fine runs perfectly on local machine and on vm when i manually click on the exe file and run it but when i automate the same via creating a service all the ss stored in blob are blank can someone help me woth whats going on
I am trying to save ss in blob file so the c# console app should work as background service in my azure vm but but the service is running the ss stored in blob are blank but when i manually run the exe file by clicking it it is fine

It's most likely that you're trying to capture the screen of a remote session (RDP). When you run locally, you're addressing the default (console) session.
You have two options. You can:

Run the application on user login, using one of the startup methods, such as RunOmce or RunOnceEx, or,
Revise your code.

If revising your code it will need to enumerate the login sessions on the VM, get the users token, and create a process in the user's session.
Assuming you're code is C#.NET (not too hard to reactor to C# or C++)...
Enumerate sessions
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class SessionHelper
{
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WTSEnumerateSessions(IntPtr hServer, int Reserved, int Version, ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo, ref int pCount);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(uint sessionId, out IntPtr phToken);

    public static uint GetActiveSessionId()
    {
        IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        int count = 0;
        if (WTSEnumerateSessions(IntPtr.Zero, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref count))
        {
            int dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            long current = (long)ppSessionInfo;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                current += dataSize;
                if (si.State == WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive)
                {
                    WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
                    return si.SessionId;
                }
            }
            WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
        }
        throw new Exception("No active sessions found");
    }

    public static IntPtr GetUserToken(uint sessionId)
    {
        if (!WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, out IntPtr token))
            throw new Exception("Could not get user token");
        return token;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
        public uint SessionId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pWinStationName;
        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

    private enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive
    }
}

Create process in user session
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class ProcessHelper
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    public static void StartCaptureProcess(IntPtr userToken)
    {
        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        
        string captureApp = @"C:\Path\To\YourCaptureApp.exe"; // Path to your screen capture application

        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(userToken, captureApp, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi))
            throw new Exception("Could not start process in user session");

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public int dwX;
        public int dwY;
        public int dwXSize;
        public int dwYSize;
        public int dwXCountChars;
        public int dwYCountChars;
        public int dwFillAttribute;
        public int dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public uint dwProcessId;
        public uint dwThreadId;
    }
}

Make sure you stay the right side of the law. The user should be aware that their session is being captured for privacy reasons, and data protection.
